# react-native-tcp not working on Android 7+

Tags: android, tcp, react-native

the app I am developing works well in all other versions of Android and iOS, but the network functionality is really centric to it.

I have no extra debugging information. But a couple of questions.

Is `react-native-tcp` being called on the main thread? In this case, wouldn't it expel an error? https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html

If so, how could I use it on other thread?

**EDIT:** Seems that you can only have one socket opened at a time, no matter if its UDP or TCP, if I try to open 2 in parallel it won't let us.

Comment: Could you explain further how is it "not working"? Is it crashing? Or just never coming back?

Comment: It meant that the package was not fulfilling its purpose: sending nor receiving messages. It did not crash or expelled warnings.